# Override REPL output

Tags: python, ipython, stdout, read-eval-print-loop

I'm looking for a way to override and parse all output in Python REPLs: eg python/IPython in a terminal, qtconsole.

This is straightforward for printed text, by overriding the print function. For a trivial example, say we would like to add an exclamation point to all output:

```
orig_print = print
print = lambda text: orig_print(text + '!')
```

Now all print commands will have the added exclamation point. This can be reset with:

```
del print
```

My question: How do I do the equivalent for REPL output? For example, how can I make it so this will work?

```
In[1]: 5 + 5
Out[2]: 10!
```

Searches have led me down the path of contextlib, subprocess and sys.stdout, but I've yet to find a solution. Have examined sympy's printing module at Github, without success.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe this is possible with `sys.settrace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried overwriting `sys.stdout.write` and it worked (with a few quirks). Someone will correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it's not gonna get much better than this.

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: tmp = sys.stdout.write

In [3]: sys.stdout.write = lambda text: tmp(text + '!')

In [4]: 5 + 5
!Out[4]: 10!
!!
!!In [5]:
```

EDIT:
I've gotten this far. Haven't figured out where that 1 extra `!` comes from.

```
In [5]: sys.stdout.write = lambda text: tmp(text if text.endswith('\n') else text + '!\r')

In [6]: 5+5
Out[6]: 10!
!
In [7]:
```

Comment: It's possible to fix the `!` on the next line be changing `tmp(text + '!')` to `tmp(text + '!\r')`

Comment: For my specific use-case, this anomaly (the extra !) didn't come up: your solution works as-is!

Comment: Does anyone have an idea for the equivalent in IPython qtconsole? It appears not to use sys.stdout. I've attempted ipykernel.iostream.OutStream.write, and IPython.sys.stdout.write.

Answer (score 1):

The standard REPL calls on `sys.displayhook` to do its work: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook

Simple example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> def displayhook(value):
...     if value is None: return
...     sys.stdout.write(repr(value) + "!\n")
... 
>>> sys.displayhook = displayhook
>>> 1 + 1
2!
```

Note that this doesn't work with ipython, but it works with the default REPL (the one you'll normally get by simply invoking `python3`) and also with IDLE (`python3 -m idlelib.idle`).

Answer (score 0):

An example that works in IPython QtConsole, based on [this article](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/02/11/altering-display-existing-classes-ipython/). This is used in conjunction with orangeink's solution overriding stdout:

```
class SciNum:
    """For compatibility with IPython's pretty printer: Contains a string,
    with a REPR that allows pretty() to print without quotes, as it would
    if using the string directly."""
    def __init__(self, text: str):
        self.text = text

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.text


def _print_ipython(arg, p, cycle) -> None:
    """Uses IPython's pretty printer to modify output for a qtconsole or notebook;
    stdout doesn't seem to work for them."""
    p.text(IPython.lib.pretty.pretty(SciNum(format(arg))))

def start() -> None:
    if not ipython_exists:
        return

    ip = IPython.get_ipython()
    # We only need to handle IPython separately if in a Qtconsole or Notebook.
    if isinstance(ip, IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell):
        return

    text_formatter = ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']

    text_formatter.for_type(float, _print_ipython)
    text_formatter.for_type(int, _print_ipython)
```